# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio, I get this error when I create a project:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.

[image: error image]

Comment: Did you already fix the error? I think it is a problem with IP address of your country. google has filtered android development services to some countries like Iran. if you manage to fix your problem please let us know how?

Answer (score 11):

Correct your app top-level `build.gradle` file and include Maven repo to download plugin from:

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Other option, it's possible to use beta version of Android Studio and upgrade to new version of AGP:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha07'
```

Comment: I tried your solutions but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I think it is a problem with the IP address of the country. Google has blocked its development services to some countries. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @RaminAr I'd suggest you setup HTTP proxy, as described in https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#proxy and configure it with any possible proxies you can find in free access. I cannot try it right now, unfortunately, so, please, let me know if it helps.